# Problems sharing the screen of my laptop with hdmi in Ubuntu

Tags: screen, sharing, hdmi, ubuntu-23.10

When I connect the HDMI from my computer to the TV, the TV screen does not show the image correctly and sometimes does not detect the computer, I clarify that I have Ubuntu and not Windows, does anyone know a possible solution? The HDMI cable is working properly and so is the TV, I have already checked it several times.

I searched the internet for information but found noth[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pyiC.jpg)ing.